# Fillna using groupby and mode not working

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, fillna

I have found several answers to this both here on Stackoverflow and other sites.

However, I keep running into errors I can't resolve.

1. If I fillna using this, it works fine, but this is just the column mode. It is not grouped.

```
df['installer'] = df['installer'].fillna(df['installer'].value_counts().idxmax())
```

2. If I try grouping with this syntax:

```
    df['installer'] = df.groupby(['region', 'basin'], sort=False)['installer'].apply(
        lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

3. If I try grouping with this, slightly different syntax:

```
    df['installer'] = df.groupby(['region', 'basin'], sort=False)['installer'].apply(
        lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Removing sort=False changes nothing.

Extra info:

```
    df['installer'] = df['installer'].astype(str).str.lower()

    print(df['installer'].isnull().sum(), '\n')  # zero nulls at this point

    df.loc[df['installer'] == '0', 'installer'] = np.nan
    df.loc[df['installer'] == 'nan', 'installer'] = np.nan
    df.loc[df['installer'] == '-', 'installer'] = np.nan

    # df['installer'] = df['installer'].fillna(df['installer'].value_counts().idxmax())
    print(df['installer'].isnull().sum(), '\n')  # 4435 null values here
    print(df3['installer'].value_counts().nlargest(25), '\n')
    df['installer'] = df.groupby(['region', 'basin'], sort=False)['installer'].apply(
        lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
    # df['installer'] = df.groupby(['region', 'district_code', 'lga'])['installer'].fillna(df['installer'].value_counts().idxmax())
    print(df['installer'].isnull().sum(), '\n')
    print(df['installer'].value_counts().nlargest(25), '\n')
```

Comment: Can you provide some data as plain text please?

Comment: I am using the Taarifa Water Pump challenge data set from DrivenData.org.  The column in question is the 'Installer' column.  I just edited my question to post additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform`:

```
vals = df.groupby(['region', 'basin'])['installer'] \
         .transform(lambda x: x.mode(dropna=False).iloc[0])
df['installer'] = df['installer'].fillna(vals)
```

Comment: I can't find the right dataset. Can you check my answer, please?